# Easiest / fastest way how to implement a counter across multiple JVM nodes

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm

Consider the problem:

I have n number of Tomcat nodes with web application serving some stateless content. For, say, 1000 first requests application must respond with 'a', for next 10000 with 'b' and for the rest - with 'c'.

I considered messaging first: application gets total served count from some storage -> if it's smaller than n then serve content 'a' -> once content is served, application sends a message -> message gets consumed -> total served count is incremented on some storage -> ...  However in this case is quite a big probability of overshoot because of slight (or huge on peek load time) delay between message served event and counter increment on the storage.

Then I considered to setup memcached-session-manager to store the counters in sort of shared session. But this looks like quite heavy for my simple case.

Could someone please suggest whether there are any straightforward way how multiple JVM instances can communicate with each other (what is applicable for my case)?

Comment: How important is consistency? If you want to change behavior after the first 10000 requests, what happens if the behavior actually changes after the first 10010 requests instead? What level of slop are you willing to tolerate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it absolutely has to be correct and you don't want delay than I think **Redis** or **Hazlecast** are your best options. **[Particularly Redis as it has atomic count like operations](http://redis.io/commands/incr)**. While you can in theory do the same with memcache, Redis is sort of designed for this exact use case (statistic counters).

You could also use a in memory db like H2 or just set a Postgres table to `unlogged` or whatever is applicable for your RDBMS to keep a not so safe in pseudo in memory table. The annoying thing about RDBMS is that [*upserting* aka `MERGE`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_%28SQL%29) are not supported consistently across all RDBMS.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you can share sessions between tomcat instances.  A tomcat server receiving the request basically sends a duplication of it's session to all the other tomcat services.

I can't help but think that you have some unexpressed need driving this request, but wish to only ask how to implement this without actually asking how to satisfy the need.  In such circumstances, needs are not met but the request often is.

For example, instead of worrying about 1000 requests to one server, and then a rotation, a simple multiple ip address to DNS hostname configuration could distribute the requests in a round-robin fashion.

You could also coordinate your sessions against a database.  Databases provide decent storage capabilities, with read consistency.  With the right configuration the "next number" could simply be read by the processing node.

Finally, there are other means, leveraging distributed computing.  For example, the request could be handled by an internal request relay which initiates a Paxos like protocol to guarantee that all processing nodes have the new "next" number.

All of these techniques are straightforward.  However, you are quickly dismissing them because they don't seem too simple to you.  Well, perhaps you are seeking an even simpler alternative, and there's no harm in that; however, getting two or more computers to agree on some item consistently, reliably, and at the same time is a bit trickier than we would all like it to be.  Feel free to initiate a new effort in this field, but perhaps you will only discover that there are real reasons for the extra overhead and complexity.  It is not a trivial problem.

--- An update ---

You know, if you can handle the requests round-robin style, and relax the need to have them ordered between servers, and know that you will only have N servers, you could implement N different request counters.

- Server 1 increments by N assuring that `count % N == 0`
- Server 2 increments by N assuring that `count % N == 1`
- ...
- Server N-1 increments by N assuring that `count % N = N-2`
- Server N increments by N assuring that `count % N = N-1`

Of course, cross-server counts would probably be out of global order in short session, but you might get a bit of what you want quickly:

- A unique count per request
- An ordering of requests on a per-server basis
- A count guaranteed to be unique across all servers
- A quick way to determine which server handled the request

What you would lack

- A true ordering of the requests across servers

Comment: Aren't sessions incompatible with "stateless"?

Comment: Isn't the idea of having an incrementing counter incompatible with the idea of "stateless"?  Stateless actions can provably produce the same output for the same input, regardless of prior call history.  It is not possible to have a stateless counter, unless you manage to push the state handling logic far away from the web handling logic, in which case, how would you meet your requirement?  The remote item would not be able to start "counting" your sessions until long after they were started.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz I added an update.  The technique is far from new, but it hinges on not needing a true ordering between servers.  It does provide some of what you want with a very simple architecture; however, it doesn't provide all of what you want.  If the simplicity of the solution becomes more important than the complete and absolute ordering, it might be useful.  Good Luck.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz another idea is to pass all the messages through a message re-writer that can append the message number before the message is distributed across the server farm.  However, it might complicate the reply path.

Answer (score 0):

Here are all the choices you have ordered from least effort to most effort required in order to set them up:

1. Use [**`memcached-session-manager`**](https://code.google.com/p/memcached-session-manager/) to store sessions across various Tomcats
2. Use a light weight database like `sqlite` and store counter in a table/collection
3. Use a shared file system and store counter in a text file
4. Use a light weight caching provider like Redis or Memcahed or Ehcache or Hazelcast
5. Use Messaging such as JMS and keep passing counter

Comment: #3 above is actually quite difficult from Java: how do you obtain exclusive access to the file? I would argue that using JDBC is one of the most straightforward (or not terribly efficient) strategies, here, yet you don't have it listed at all.

Comment: I didn't realize that sqlite was multi-process. Thanks.

Comment: I'm surprised he didn't mention Redis (`INCR`). If he mentioned Redis I will just delete my answer.

Comment: @AdamGent: Edited to include Redis in the list.